# Searching though values of a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains `Product` values with properties like `description`.
In a `textbox1_textchanged` handler, I want to search the Products in the dictionary that has certain text within the `description`.

I've tried this:

```
var values = (from pv in mydictionary
              where pv.Value.description.Contains(textBox1.Text)
              select pv.Value);
```

*This code isn't working because the second key I pressed values var values is empty.*

All the examples I found are searching through the keys but I need to search through the values of the dictionary.

Comment: So what keys do you press, and what is the content of mydictionary? Does it contain the text you search for?

Comment: By the way, your example does not compile, you need to stick in the `where` keyword first on the second line.

Comment: Yes, I've missed where keyword but in my code is and doesn't works. In the dictionary value I only have an object with id_product, name, description, and I want to find product names writting them in textbox and searching in dictionary's value.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit and added that `where` as it seems it was just a typo here.  I wasn't sure what you were saying in the line after the code so I just left it alone.

Comment: thanks for that. The line after the code is that I've found examples with this code but with key instead of value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have isn't valid code however.  You are trying to filter the values that have a certain description but you're missing a key element.  You need to add the `where` clause to complete it.

```
var values =
    from pv in mydictionary
    where pv.Value.description.Contains(textBox1.Text)
    select pv.Value;
```

A better way to write this however would be to just look at the values of the dictionary.

```
var values =
    from value in mydictionary.Values // Note: we're looking through the values only,
                                      // not all the key/value pairs in the dictionary
    where value.description.Contains(textBox1.Text)
    select value;
```

To make it case-insensitive, you could try using [`String.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) since it's one of the few comparisons that could do the search ignoring the case.

```
var values =
    from value in mydictionary.Values
    where value.description
               .IndexOf(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
               // any value that isn't `-1` means it contains the text
               // (or the description was empty)
    select value;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've missed where keyword, but with it it doesn't works. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well that would depend on what values you have in your dictionary and what text you are searching for.  Since you haven't given any example inputs, I cannot tell you where you went wrong.  Note that this search is case-sensitive and includes everything that is in the text box.  So if you have extra spaces typed in, you're probably not going to find the items you're looking for.

Comment: And how can I search in the key/value pairs?

Comment: In my dictionary values there is an object with description="cocacola" and when I'm typing the name in the textbox, if I write "co" finds cocacola, but when I write "coc" it doesn't find anything

Comment: What you originally had looked through the key/value pairs.  But since it didn't really matter what the key was, it was unnecessary (hence my suggestion).  Also, please include that information in the question.  It should still work but there is still some information that you're not showing that is causing problems.  If `"cocacola".Contains("coc")` returns `true`, then all the code seen here should work.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explain me well. Thanks to all. Is any way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Case-insensitive version added.

Comment: why not use Lambdas, I don't understand why people even bother with this long syntax form of querying with LINQ

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var values =  mydictionary.Where(k => k.Value.description.Contains(textBox1.Text))
                          .Select(k => k.Value);
```

Comment: is the first thing I've tested but Value doesnt have method contains.

Comment: @uoah I missed description. My snipped is essentially the same as your query but it seemed like you where missing the `where` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Change the where clause to:

```
where value != null && value.description != null && value.description.Contains(textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: But consider also adding your values to a second dictionary using the description as a key!

Comment: I've considered but maybe I have some values with the same description, then I can't use description as key.

Answer (score -1):

One other thing you may want to consider is that the string.Contains method will do a case sensitive search.

```
var str = "The quick brown fox blah";
var test1 = "quick";
var test2 = "Quick";

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} CONTAINS {1} = {2}", str, test1, str.Contains(test1)));

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} CONTAINS {1} = {2}", str, test2, str.Contains(test2)));

//Output
The quick brown fox blah CONTAINS quick = True
The quick brown fox blah CONTAINS Quick = False
```

If you cant a case insensitive search so that both of the above would return true you should put the strings in lower case first ...

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} CONTAINS {1} = {2}", str, test1, str.ToLower().Contains(test1.ToLower())));

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} CONTAINS {1} = {2}", str, test2, 
str.ToLower().Contains(test2.ToLower())));

//Output
The quick brown fox blah CONTAINS quick = True
The quick brown fox blah CONTAINS Quick = True
```